# Disagree with downvoted question

Tags: discussion

I asked this question and got downvoted immediately.

[Implementing a score system similar to Moon Patrol](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/160057/implementing-a-score-system-similar-to-moon-patrol)

I disagree that it should be a bad question. Now I cannot ask any more question because of this and I feel very discouraged because my effort is good.

Comment: Is there a question you wanted to ask or simply complain about a single downvote?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Why doesn't this site work as intended?

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz Possibly relevant: [things another user did to get un-banned](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2708/33287)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for sharing this in meta.

I'm sorry you have trouble with the site. Unfortunately, *question bans* don't happen overnight, or from a single question:

> At Stack Exchange, asking questions is a privilege, not a right. If a user cannot demonstrate, **after asking a reasonable number of questions**, that their contributions are making the site better (or at very least, not making it worse) then they will be blocked from asking further questions until they have demonstrated their ability to contribute positively.
>
> ([Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), emphasis mine.)

Looking at [your profile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/9310/niklas-rosencrantz?tab=questions&sort=newest), aside from making me happy that you've been around for so long [image], we can see you had some questions that have been downvoted in the (distant) past. Stack Exchange does not disclose what governs question bans—even with mods—but reading the help page linked above, it seems to be related a lot to *all* of your questions scores, mainly those questions with a negative score.

And by *all*, I mean that you should consider the closed and the deleted ones too.

So, I suggest you follow the guidance from the help center page linked above and try to improve your questions. Take all the comments that you have received into consideration, they often provide very good feedback on why people downvote.

---

At a glance, you generally seem to add a lot of code that is not relevant to the question. If the code that you need to add seems to big, perhaps you should simply describe the algorithm.

Also, often, asking off-topic questions brings down the anger of the gods, which causes users to downvote, for some reasons. If you can find some good ways to bring these off-topic question on-topic, you'd probably get *some* upvotes, and/or maybe some users could remove their downvote, if they're still around (*disclaimer: I give no guarantee, as I have no control this—I'm just a* m*od*).

In the future, avoid asking questions that are off-topic. You might want to discuss this in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development), where off-topic stuff is allowed and where other users could give you a hand, at least to get you started.

---

You have *some* deleted questions that have negative scores. When you've tried your best with those that are not deleted, and you find yourself stuck again, please @AlexandreVaillancourt ping me in the comments, we'll see what questions you could improve once un-deleted (I won't just undelete them now because the system might deleted them within 24 hours if you don't edit them).